# Является ли вопрос дубликатом если в ответе на другом вопросе нет всей требуемой информации?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Буквально вчера я задал вот такой вопрос: [Что такое метка в JavaScript и как она работает?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1513117/)

Позже я нашёл информацию об этом и решил написать само-ответ т.к. не заметил чтобы на Stack Overflow были похожие вопросы. Позже, <s>по сложившейся традиции</s> Grundy закрывает мой вопрос как дубликат этого вопроса [Метка строки в js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/631243/)

Я пришёл к тому что в ответе Grundy есть 2/3 пунктов, которые требовались.

- ✅ Была информация о том предназначении меток
- ✅ Была и информация о том какое у них применение
- ❌ Единственного чего не было, это примеров неправильного использования (то-есть тех в которых вызывается ошибка) и не было примеров правильного использования.

Исходя из [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) вы должны цитировать информацию, относящуюся к вопросу. В моём ответе я написал и примеры правильного и неправильного использования, включил ошибки и добавил ссылки на источники и добавил информацию о том что именно вызывает ошибки (Этого в ответе Grundy откровенно говоря не хватает). Правильные примеры также были добавлены.

Теперь сам вопрос, можно ли считать мой вопрос дубликатом другого, если в нём не содержится вся требуемая информация, но при этом имеется часть ответов на вопросы? Может вопросы вообще стоит объединить? Может быть я не прав и в ответе Grundy всё-таки есть то, чего я не заметил?

Я согласен с тем что *правильные* примеры в случае с ответов Grundy не обязательно т.к. в другом ТС вопросе уже знал как использовать label'ы и смысла в этом мало. (Но это не отменяет факта того что нужны *неправильные* примеры, где показаны ошибки)

Comment: Я верно понимаю, что дубликатом отмечен Вопрос, а претензии у вас к Ответам? Так же, вы легко можете перенести свои уточнения и ответы в более полный Вопрос и его Ответы?

Comment: @Kromster `Я верно понимаю, что дубликатом отмечен Вопрос, а претензии у вас к Ответам?` к другому вопросу у меня претензий нет, он правильный и ничего плохо в нём я не вижу, а вот ответ на вопрос не подходит под мой вопрос (по крайней мере полностью). Поэтому я не считаю свой вопрос дубликатом. `Так же, вы легко можете перенести свои уточнения и ответы в более полный Вопрос и его Ответы?` - и вправду, глуплю, но не уверен что это поможет т.к. его легко могут снова закрыть, но я попытаюсь, спасибо за совет.

Comment: Если вопросы скорее схожи, то они дубликаты. Если не схожи - надо отредактировать и уточнить разницу. *"т.к. его легко могут снова закрыть"* - что вы имеете ввиду? Ответы на вопрос являющийся "основным" не могут просто так "закрыть".

Comment: @Kromster `что вы имеете ввиду?` - я про мой вопрос, его могут снова закрыть.

Comment: @Kromster я написал что в своём вопросе что также требую ошибки в ответе, но его всё равно закрыли. Я только что перечитал второй вопрос, похоже что я его плохо читал, не совсем понял вашей мысли сразу.

Comment: @ΝNL993, лучше организуйте движение против закрытия любых вопросов, как дубликатов. Это решит подобные проблемы в будущем (особенно, если сменить цель существования данного сайта с накопления "базы знаний" на *помощь конкретным людям*)

Comment: Вопрос - дубль, ответ - нет. Вывод: новый вопрос нужно закрыть как дубль старого и объединить эти два вопроса.

Comment: Чтобы показать сообществу, что вопрос решен, не забудьте поставить зелёную галочку слева от ответа. И зднсь, и в том вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если имеются два или более вопроса, содержание которых идентично, то дубликатом должен быть тот, на который дан менее подробный ответ, а оригиналом - вопрос с наиболее полным ответом. Время публикации учитываться не должно.

То, чем занимается Grundy - это накрутка собственного рейтинга за счёт публикации ссылок на собственные ответы.

Comment: `Если имеются два или более вопроса, содержание которых идентично, то дубликатом должен быть тот, на который дан менее подробный ответ, а оригиналом - вопрос с наиболее полным ответом. Время публикации учитываться не должно.` -- это просто ваше мнение, или так и вправду решается что дубликат, а что нет?

Comment: @ΝNL993 это мнение, но так частенько делают. Я не помню точной логики, но с дубликами есть проблема, что идёт переадресация на оригинал. И следовательно, если подробный ответ будет не в оригинале - его будет сложнее найти.

Comment: @NNL993, это мнение, выставленное на голосование. Оно основано именно на том, что на дубликатах ссылка идёт на оригинал. αλεχολυτ очень точно всё выразил.

Comment: "То, чем занимается Grundy - это накрутка собственного рейтинга за счёт публикации ссылок на собственные ответы" - есть доказательства, кроме как ваших догадок? @Grundy достаточно давно на ruSO и у него золотой знак по JS (1640 сообщений по этой метке) и это вполне естественно, что у он уже отвечал на подобные вопросы раньше, а сейчас закрывает их дубликатами на свои же ответы. Не вижу никаких гнустных мыслей в этом. Если я тоже отвечал на подобные вопросы, я поступал точно так же. Потому считаю ваш ответ необоснованной клеветой

Answer (score 4):

Если честно ваш вопрос и ответ (лично для меня) - это просто более развёрнутая версия вопроса и ответа, который указал [Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy), потому (лично для меня) он верно закрыт как дубликат

Плюс ко всему:

- Ваш вопрос не был удалён
- И ответ и вопрос не заминусованы, а значит его не удалит система просто так
- И вопрос и ответ всё ещё будут набирать голоса, если это покажется кому-то полезным (+1 от меня)
- Вы всё ещё можете изменять и вопрос и ответ, чтобы вносить нужные вам уточнения

Исходя из всего этого не вижу абсолютно никаких проблем с закрытием вашего вопроса как дубликат

P.S. Не надо в заголовках писать кликбейты типа "Странный синстаксис в JavaScript" - это не название ролика для `YouTube`-а

Comment: Интересно за что два минуса, минусующие, поясните?

Comment: @Kromster просто кому-то не понравилось мнение. Это же мета.

Comment: "Плюс ко всему:" - минус ко всему: если вы не залогинены, вы вообще этот вопрос не увидите, вас будет переадресовывать на вопрос, на который закрыли дубликатом. Если в этом вопросе ответ более развернутый, то полезнее, если будут видеть именно этот ответ.

Comment: @insolor Абсолютно с вами не согласен - https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJr3S.jpg. С чего вы это взяли?

Comment: @EzioMercer не знаю при чем тут скриншот выдача гугла, но вообще да, сейчас проверил, не перекидывает (хз, какое-то время назад с таким сталкивался, сейчас не могу воспроизвести). Но в любом случае, закрывать дубликатом имеет смысл на вопрос с более полным ответом.

Comment: @insolor С этим спорить не стану, есть логика в этом. Но стоит конкретизировать что означает "более полный ответ". Т.е. интуитивно я понимаю о чём вы, но если мы примем такой подход глобально по всему сайту, то это нужно будет конкретизировать. Кто-то может добавить незначительную деталь к своему вопросу/ответу и сказать, что он "более подробный" и нужны будут объективные критерии "подробности". Или например кто-то дал ссылку на документацию, а другой помимо ссылки скопипастил текст из документации - это "более подробно" или нет? И подвохов может быть ещё куча это то что первое пришло в голову

Comment: @insolor [как оказалось](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125807/339911), редирект с дубликатов на оригинал работает только для вопросов **без ответов**.